# OPcache class preloading | where is the preload file generated by cache:clear command?

Tags: php, symfony, preload, opcache

I'm using Symfony 4.4 with PHP 7.4.7

The Symfony documentation indicates that cache:clear command will generate a "file called preload.php in the config/ directory"
(see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-preloading-symfony-applications-in-php-7-4#opcache-preloading-in-symfony).
However, this is not the case.

In addition,
the blog https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-preloading-symfony-applications-in-php-7-4#opcache-preloading-in-symfony tells us that the preload file is generated in `/path/to/project/var/cache/<env>/`

Is the official documentation deprecated or is there something I've not understood ?

So i don't really know how to use correctly this feature...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Most possibly very late to the party, but I managed to find the solution for this issues. I can't find it in the 4.4 docs, but it's there in the 5.3 docs.

> If this file is missing, run this command to reinstall the Symfony
> Flex recipe: `composer recipes:install symfony/framework-bundle --force -v`.

I've tried this and it creates the `config/preload.php` file, but it also changes these files, too:

```sh
modified:   .env
modified:   .gitignore
modified:   config/packages/framework.yaml
modified:   config/services.yaml
modified:   public/index.php
modified:   symfony.lock
```

Depending on what you have in `.gitignore`, you might see a lot of changes. Make sure they are relevant and are not breaking your application.